# How often and where should I check if the Auth0 access token has expired in a React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, auth0

I have a React app that uses Axios, Redux, and React Router. What is the best location and best way to check if the token expired?

1. Intercept each API request using Axios and check for token expiration before sending out the request
2. Set an interval at that runs every 30 seconds or so to check if the token expired.

If the token expires, automatically log the user out

Answer (score 0):

Since the expiration timestamp is in the token, you should only have to check it once per token on the client side. You can then set a timeout to refresh the token before it expires so ideally, you don't have to log out the user. Note, this is for user convenience only, not for security, since clients could fudge their system clocks.

The back end should verify the token for every request.